# Tags - [serps] are the same as [search-results], right?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, tag-synonyms

Are the tags [serps](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/serps) (search engine results pages) and [search-results](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/search-results) (search results) the same?

If so, should (edit) [serps](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/serps) be synonymized into [search-results](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/search-results)?

Doing a spot check of the tagged questions, the tags appear to be used interchangeably.

Comment: Usually we wait a few days to solicit feedback from everybody before performing any tag merges.

Comment: Yes, the `serps` tag should be changed to a [tag synonym](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/suggest-tag-synonyms) of the more commonly recognized `search-results` tag/term..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The two are similar enough to merge.  I would prefer to merge [serps](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/serps) into [search-results](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/search-results) because the former is jargon and the latter is likely to more widely understood.

Comment: I agree. `serps` has more questions tagged, but `search-results` is more immediately apparent to people who are not familiar with the term `serp`.